# Kendo Grid for Angular2/4 - block grid while loading data

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to block/disable Kendo Angular2/4 Grid when it is loading a data.

What is the best approach?

In my component i have a `isWorking` variable which is true/false if the data are loading(ajax API call):

`export class GridFilterComponent {
    public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
    public state: State = { skip: 0, take: 10 };
    public isWorking = true;`

The only option I found, without using is to hide/show grid using `*ngIf="!isWorking"` on the `kendo-grid` element, but it is a bit clunky and not very user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put grid in `<div>`

```
<div [ngClass]="isWorking ? 'gridDisabled': ''">
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"></kendo-grid>
</div>

.gridDisabled{
    pointer-events: none;   
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Short version:

```
<div [class.gridDisabled]="isWorking">
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: Shorter version `[class.gridDisabled]="isWorking"`